# Ant script from DOS prompt

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ant, ear

How to exexute RAD specific ANT task "**earExport**" with WAS JRE outside of RAD. 
 info:
JAVA_HOME is set to

```
C:\Program~1\Java\jdk1.6.0_28
```

ANT_HOME is set to

```
C:\ant1.8\ant
```

RAD's JRE location is

```
C:\Program~1\IBM\RAD7\runtimes\base_v7\java\jre <br/>
```

Build Script Location:

```
C:\myProject\BuildScript\build-myProject.xml
C:\myProject\BuildScript\build-myProject.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

The **%JAVA_HOME%** variable is used to find the JRE, you can build a bat file where you set the variable and call ant with the task

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be doing this a lot, I would suggest that you instead create a batch file that sets the `%JAVA_HOME%` environment variable for you and opens a new command prompt.

This way, you wouldn't have to modify your general `%JAVA_HOME%` property or your Ant scripts.

Basically like this:

```
@echo off
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\IBM\RAD7\runtimes\base_v7\java\jre

start cmd.exe
```

When you run the above it will open a new command prompt with JAVA_HOME set to that location for only that instance of cmd.exe. When you close it, your `%JAVA_HOME%` will point to your original location.

Answer (score 0):

try the RAD build utility

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rad.install.doc/topics/c_install_build_utility_8.html